# data structure for indexing big file

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, data-structures, complexity-theory

I need to build an index for a very big (50GB+) ASCII text file which will enable me to provide fast random read access to file (get nth line, get nth word in nth line). I've decided to use `List<List<long>> map`, where `map[i][j]` element is position of jth word of ith line in the file.

I will build the index sequentially, i.e. read the whole file and populating index with `map.Add(new List<long>())` (new line) and `map[i].Add(position)` (new word). I will then retrieve specific word position with `map[i][j]`.

The only problem I see is that I can't predict total count of lines/words, so I will bump into O(n) on every `List` reallocation, no idea of how I can avoid this.

Are there any other problems with the data structure I chose for the task? Which structure could be better?

**UPD**: File will not be altered during the runtime. There are no other ways to retrieve content except what I've listed.

Answer (score 6):

1. Increasing size of a large list is very expensive operation; so, it's better to reserve list size at the beginning.
2. I'd suggest to use 2 lists. The first contains indexes of words within file, and the second contains indexes in the first list (index of the first word in the appropriate line).
3. You are very likely to exceed all available RAM. And when the system starts to page in/page out GC-managed RAM, performance of the program will be completely killed. I'd suggest to store your data in memory-mapped file rather than in managed memory. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx

UPD memory mapped files are effective, when you need to work with huge amounts of data not fitting in RAM. Basically, it's your the only choice if your index becomes bigger than available RAM.

Comment: Could you please add more details about (3)? How these 2 cases would be different? (any links would be great as well).